# Avoiding creating the same query twice in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pretty much simple and self explanatory SQL statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getAllDebatesForAlias](@SubjectAlias nchar(30))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM tblDebates
    WHERE (SubjectID1 in (SELECT SubjectID FROM tblSubjectAlias WHERE SubjectAlias = @SubjectAlias)) 
        OR (SubjectID2 in (SELECT SubjectID FROM tblSubjectAlias WHERE SubjectAlias = @SubjectAlias)) ;
END
```

I am certain that there is a way to make this statement more efficient, at least get rid of that multiple creation of the same table in the `in` section, i.e., the

```
SELECT SubjectID FROM tblSubjectAlias WHERE SubjectAlias = @SubjectAlias
```

part.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select d.* from tblDebates d
where exists
(select 1
 from tblSubjectAlias s
 where s.SubjectID in (d.SubjectID1, d.SubjectID2) and
       s.SubjectAlias = @SubjectAlias)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.*
FROM tblDebates d
inner join tblSubjectAlias s on s.SubjectID in (d.SubjectID1, d.SubjectID2)
where s.SubjectAlias = @SubjectAlias
```

Comment: Not quite the same; if there are multiple subjects with the same alias, each Debate record may be returned multiple times (once for each matching subject).

Comment: You are right. A `select distinct ...` might be suitable for the OPs needs.